# Output lost using xargs using curl

Tags: curl, xargs

Using `curl` alone as

> curl 'https://abc.ai/getMultiDashboard/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0' -H
> 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'
> --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: [https://abc.ai/'](https://abc.ai/%27) -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.561275388.1601468723;
> _hjid=ecd3d778-b7f5-4f7f-b3ef-6f9f12b13d66; 54651cc_an=4; _gid=GA1.2.1366208807.1601560229; _hjTLDTest=1; 54651cc_data=JTdCJTIyaWQlMjIlM0ElMjJkZW1vdXNlciUyMiUyQyUyMm4lMjIlM0ElMjJkZWhY2Nlc3NUb2tlbiUyMiUzQSUyMjA2MTk3NjM3NTgwOGE2N2RmZjlhMmJlOWJmODE5NDQzJTIyJTdE;
> 54651cc_loggedin=1; 54651cc_sound=true; 54651cc_read=true;
> 54651cc_popup=true; 54651cc_disablelastseen=false;
> 54651cc_usertype=loginuser; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1;
> _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; iridium=s%3A8ZGd7Mol31n_Y8OCLq39dHoo3_mIlRhZ.pFQWz5gG9McKsQLzOikcTBmmb2Wcrxo%2B9u9iPpqoyxw;
> pageUrl=/#/dashboard/18; _gat_gtag_UA_97985973_5=1'

**output**

> [{"dashboard_id": 18, "user_id": "demouser", "dashboard_name":
> "My_dashboard_1", "description": "Test description One",
> "creation_date": "2020-09-21 10:13:00", "dashboard_config": null}]

Running with

> xargs -I % -P 2 curl
> 'https://abc.ai/getMultiDashboard/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0' -H
> 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'
> --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: [https://abc.ai/'](https://abc.ai/%27) -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.561275388.1601468723; _hjid=ecd3d778-b7f5-4f7f-b3ef-6f9f12b13d66; 54651cc_an=4; _gid=GA1.2.1366208807.1601560229; _hjTLDTest=1; 54651cc_data=JTdCJTIyaWQlMjIlM0ElMjJkZW1vdXNlciUyMiUyQyUyMm4lMjIlM0ElMjJkZWhY2Nlc3NUb2tlbiUyMiUzQSUyMjA2MTk3NjM3NTgwOGE2N2RmZjlhMmJlOWJmODE5NDQzJTIyJTdE;
> 54651cc_loggedin=1; 54651cc_sound=true; 54651cc_read=true;
> 54651cc_popup=true; 54651cc_disablelastseen=false;
> 54651cc_usertype=loginuser; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1;
> _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; iridium=s%3A8ZGd7Mol31n_Y8OCLq39dHoo3_mIlRhZ.pFQWz5gG9McKsQLzOikcTBmmb2Wcrxo%2B9u9iPpqoyxw;
> pageUrl=/#/dashboard/18; _gat_gtag_UA_97985973_5=1' 
> < <(printf '%s\n' {1..2})

**outputs**
root@root:~#

Basically, i think xargs i unable to parse multiline curl cmd, pls assist me in troubleshooting

**UPDATE**
with exact same cmd logic , I get different result it actually output HTTP response
`xargs -I % -P 2 curl -I "https://youtube.com" < <(printf '%s\n' {1..2})`

```
HTTP/2 301
content-length: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
location: https://www.youtube.com/
date: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 18:04:05 GMT
content-type: text/html
server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
x-xss-protection: 0
alt-svc: h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

HTTP/2 301
content-length: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
location: https://www.youtube.com/
date: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 18:04:05 GMT
content-type: text/html
server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
x-xss-protection: 0
alt-svc: h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
```

Comment: I want to replay same GET request shown in first command in parallel e.g 40 times.

Comment: With `-I %`, all the `%`s are replaced with `1` or `2`.

Comment: `curl` doesn't need superuser privileges, you don't need to run it as `root` (and probably shouldn't, `curl` has had many vulnerabilities in the past).

Comment: Try echo 'https://abc.ai/getMultiDashboard/' -H ... gat_gtag_UA_97985973_5=1' | xargs curl

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas pls see updated response

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas are you suggesting all the '%' inside the request are replace with 1 and 2 that's evil :( what can I do to escape it

Comment: With `-I %`, you're explicitly asking for `%` to be replaced with the words `xargs` is meant to process. Use `-I something-that-does-not-appear-on-the-command-line` if you don't want the input words to be used.

Comment: Re: your edit,`curl -I "https://youtube.com"` gives the same HTTP redirect output.

Comment: In any case, note that those `curl` command will be run in parallel, so their output may end-up interleaved. You may want to use GNU parallel instead if  you'd rather make sure the outputs are serialised.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas for e.g `seq 4 | parallel -n0 -j2 "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://httpbin.org/post -X POST -d '{\"url\":\"http://google.com/\"}'"` if i need to run 400 consecutively should I only change the `j` parameter

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas other issue with `xargs` and `curl` combo is used together for request which timesout then I need to wait for 1 request to timeout before I can send the next can I send it all together without needing to worry about timeouts